# Mudblazor DatePicker binding works one way only

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-5, mudblazor

I have been trying to bind mudblazor datepicker to a DateTime property using Date.

```
<MudDatePicker Label="Start Date" Date="@StartDate" />
<MudTextField Label="SelectedDate" @bind-Value="@StartDate" />
<MudText Typo="Typo.h3">Selected Date is: @StartDate</MudText>

@code
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public string DateString { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried this code on their [site](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet) and in visual studio
The code will update the Date Picker and my Text output when leaving the text field, this is normal behavior. However, I want to change the Text based on my selection of Date picker. I have tried binding to date and value. both don't reflect the selection I have made.

I have checked the documentation on their site and there is nothing on how to handle binding beyond what I am doing.

If any one knows how to bind Date picker in mudblazor please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for anyone interested here is the answer:
A Date picker in Mudblazor will only bind to a nullable DateTime, and I have to use @bind-Date. So my sample code that should work looks like this:

```
<MudDatePicker Label="Start Date" @bind-Date="@StartDate" />
<MudTextField Label="SelectedDate" @bind-Value="@StartDate" />
<MudText Typo="Typo.h3">Selected Date is: @StartDate</MudText>

@code
    {
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Quite a weird flow compaired to the rest! but thanks for sharing, you saved me quite some time of trail and error.

Comment: I was using a DateRangePicker, and manually implementing the Value and OnChanged rather than using a @bind. What worked for me was that the object needed to update. I couldn't just set DateRange.Start and DateRange.End. I needed to give it a new object for the UI to update i.e. DateRange = new DateRange(Start, End); The binding value also did not need to be nullable. The key was assigning a new object

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with MudDateRangePicker.
I found that I could use a nullable or a non-nullable DateRange variable but if I wanted to get the currently selected Start & End dates from a callback function, I would have to call the DateRangePicker.Close() method *before* I checked the dates.
Just FYI if anyone else is looking at this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).